# Не удается установить размер изображения в swf

Tags: flash

Доброго времени суток! Необходимо элементарное вращение вокруг своей оси изображения, в первую очеред решил использовать flash, с action script почти не знаком - нашел вот такое решение:

```
package
{
  import flash.display.*; 
  import flash.events.*; 
  import flash.net.*; 
  import flash.utils.Timer;

  public class RotateImage extends Sprite 
  { 
    // Загрузчик изображения 
    private var loader:Loader; 
    // Таймер вращения 
    private var rotateTimer:Timer; 
    // Угол вращения 
    private var angle:int; 
    // Конструктор 
    public function RotateImage():void 
    { 
      // Вызываем конструктор базового класса 
      super(); 
      // Устанавливаем угол 
      this.angle = 0; 
      // Создаем загрузчик 
      this.loader = new Loader(); 
      // Назначаем обработчик события окончания 
      // загрузки изображения 
      this.loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, imageCompleteHandler); 
      // Загружаем изображение 
      this.loader.load(new URLRequest("logo.jpg")); 
      // Обработчик вращения 
      this.rotateTimer = new Timer(10); 
      this.rotateTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, rotateTimerHandler); 
    } 
    // Обработчик события окончания загрузки изображения 
    private function imageCompleteHandler(evt:Event):void 
    { 
      // Размещаем изображение на флешке
      this.addChild(this.loader); 
      // Отступ от левого края 
      this.loader.x = 200; 
      // Отступ сверху 
      this.loader.y = 50; 
      // Смещаем точку поворота в центр 
      this.loader.content.x = -this.loader.content.width / 2; 
      // Запускаем таймер вращения 
      this.rotateTimer.start(); 
    } 
    // Обработчик таймера вращения 
    private function rotateTimerHandler(evt:TimerEvent):void 
    { 
      // Один угол за один такт 
      this.angle += 1; 
      // Обнуляем значение угла, при достижении полного поворота 
      if(this.angle > 359) this.angle = 0; 
      // Вращаем изображение 
      this.loader.rotationY = this.angle; 
    } 
  } 
}
```

проблема в том, что размер изображения logo.jpg проигрываемого во flash не соответствует реальному размеру logo.jpg лежащего на сервере, в flash оно гараздо меньше, в <object> указываю реальные ширину и высоту изображения, при изменении значений свойств атрибутов width и height у <object> меняется и размер изображения, прошу помощи с целью устранения проблемы, т.е. как мне указать явно размер в action script, или может не в этом дело ... спасибо за внимание !

Comment: Полный урл на лого выдайте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот как указать размер swf (флешки) и изображения через AS3.

```
package
{
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.utils.Timer;

[SWF (width="640", height="480")] // Размер флешки.
public class RotateImage extends Sprite
{
    // Конструктор 
    public function RotateImage():void 
    { 
        // Вызываем конструктор базового класса 
        super(); 
        // Создаем загрузчик 
        var loader:Loader = new Loader(); 
        // Назначаем обработчик события окончания загрузки изображения 
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imageCompleteHandler); 
        // Загружаем изображение 
        loader.load(new URLRequest("logo.jpg")); 
    } 
    // Обработчик события окончания загрузки изображения 
    private function imageCompleteHandler(evt:Event):void 
    { 
        // Извлекаем битмап карту из загрузчика.
        var bm:Bitmap = evt.target.content as Bitmap;
        // Кидаем карту на основной спрайт.
        this.addChild( bm );
        this.x = 200; // отступ слева
                    // Размер изображения.
        bm.width = 120; // новая ширина
        bm.height = 70; // новая высота
        // Смещаем точку поворота в центр 
        bm.x = - bm.width/2; 
        // Отступ сверху 
        bm.y = 50; 
        // Запускаем таймер вращения 
        var rotateTimer:Timer = new Timer(10); 
        rotateTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, rotateTimerHandler);
        rotateTimer.start(); 
    } 
    // Обработчик таймера вращения 
    private function rotateTimerHandler(evt:TimerEvent):void 
    { 
        // Вращаем изображение 
        this.rotationY += 1; 
    } 
}
```

}